# How do i customize css file of a plugin from wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

How do i customize the css file of plugin that installed on wordpress ?
I want to make the form label smaller.
Help please , Thank you.

[image]

Comment: This plugin call Event Manager

Answer (score 1):

you can use additional CSS for it.
You will find it under Appearance->Customize->Additional CSS.
Just select correct class or id and place code in additional CSS.
For more details you can check [Customization](https://www.fasstechies.com/how-to-easily-customize-styling-on-wordpress/)